# How to understand a one-line code that extract subset dictionary with selected key and value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a Python project. I am creating a subset dictionary from the main dictionary, the subset dictionary only takes the key, value pairs that are under keys: 'E', 'O', 'L'.

I found this code is working perfectly:

```
{key: self._the_main_dict[key] for key in self._the_main_dict.keys() & {'E', 'O', 'L'}}
```

However, I would like to understand how it works. How could this be expressed in multiple lines of code? I guess it is something like: for key in ....

Comment: You can read about dictionary comprehensions in python. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In short python has comprehensions that can provide one liner for datatype construction using for loops.**

Here, this is an example of dictionary comprehension.

```
{key: self._the_main_dict[key] for key in self._the_main_dict.keys() & {'E', 'O', 'L'}}
```

This code can be extended to:

```
output = dict()
for key in self._the_main_dict.keys() & {'E', 'O', 'L'}:
  output[key] = self._the_main_dict[key]
```

`output` is the response provided by above dictionary comprehension.

`self._the_main_dict.keys() & {'E', 'O', 'L'}`. If you're confused on this. This is just an Intersection operation between two sets. Yeah! Sets and Venn diagram you used to study in mathematics :D

Answer (score 0):

This works by creating an [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) of the dict's keys with the set containing E, O and L. In long form, this could be written as:

```py
all_keys = self._the_main_dict.keys()
keys_of_interest = {'E', 'O', 'L'}
filtered_keys = all_keys & keys_of_interest
# alternatively:
filtered_keys = keys_of_interest.intersection(all_keys)
```

These keys are then iterated over to create the resulting dict via a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict). A clearer way would be to explicitly specify the condition rather than implicitly through the merging step:

```py
{key: self._the_main_dict[key] for key in self._the_main_dict.keys() if key in {'E', 'O', 'L'}}
```

Comment: lol, we both added the `if key in` rewrite to our answers at the same time.

Comment: @Barmar gotta fight the garbage code!

Comment: @Jan Wilamowski Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `keys()` method returns a set-like object containing the keys of the dictionary. Sets use the `&` operator to perform intersection, so

```
self._the_main_dict.keys() & {'E', 'O', 'L'}
```

is equivalent to

```
self._the_main_dict.keys().intersection({'E', 'O', 'L'})
```

and returns the subset of the keys that are in the `{'E', 'O', 'L'}` set.

Then the rest of the dictionary comprehension creates a new dictionary containing `key: self._the_main_dict[key]` for those keys.

A more common way to write this would be:

```
{key: self._the_main_dict[key] 
    for key in self._the_main_dict.keys() 
    if key in {'E', 'O', 'L'}}
```